# Server process continues after Browser tab is closed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASPX page which when is submitted into a new tab starts a server side process. Sometimes the process takes too long and a user closes the tab the page is running in. However, the process continues running and that creates a big problem. My question is why the process continues running and how can I kill it when the tab is closed. I do have a code in the code behind where I can kill the process, I just can't find a way of executing it. Please, help. Release is coming.
Closing Browser actually help.

Thanks

code to detect tab closing event:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            e.returnValue = '';
            ... execute server code
        });
```

The event is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way to cancel the process on the back-end, the best you can do is use the JavaScript events `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` to detect when the user closes a tab, and then send a request to kill the process.

Comment: Nope, these events are not deteted when I am closing the tab. see my updated question

Comment: What else have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to find a way of catching tab closing event. So far, no event fires for me. Is it important how the new tab was opened? New tab opens when a form on the main tab is submitted with a target="_blank".